# How to deal with timed out semaphore wait

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I have two threads being synchronized with semaphores. Thread1 is waiting for a sem_post() by Thread2 using sem_timedwait(). But I fear that whenever timeout happens, the corresponding sem_post() which may  happen at a later time, will increment the semaphore value and hence when the next iteration of the sem_timedwait() occurs for Thread1, it will unlock without waiting for its corresponding sem_post() on Thread2. I feel that this is a very generic issue and should have a standard way of dealing with it.

Comment: Please share a code snippet of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If the synchronization is important, then why are you letting timeouts happen at all?